# How to restore /lib/modules/4.4.0-116-generic/kernel/drivers/usb/serial/usbserial.ko?

Tags: drivers

I accidentally overwrote /lib/modules/4.4.0-116-generic/kernel/drivers/usb/serial/usbserial.ko on Ubuntu 14.04. How can I get this back?

Answer (score 2):

Simply reinstall the package that contains the file.

To find what package contains `/lib/modules/4.4.0-116-generic/kernel/drivers/usb/serial/usbserial.ko`, run:

```
dpkg -S /lib/modules/4.4.0-116-generic/kernel/drivers/usb/serial/usbserial.ko
```

This should output (in your case):

```
linux-image-4.4.0-116-generic: /lib/modules/4.4.0-116-generic/kernel/drivers/usb/serial/usbserial.ko
```

Simply reinstall the package:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall linux-image-4.4.0-116-generic
```

If this does not fix it:

```
sudo apt-get purge linux-image-4.4.0-116-generic
sudo apt-get install linux-image-4.4.0-116-generic
```

Comment: Thanks, I ran the dpkg command but the ../usbserial.ko path doesn't exist. Maybe something else somehow installed it?

Comment: Oh, I manually entered the path and it did return `linux-image-extra-4.4.0-116-generic: /lib/modules/4.4.0-116-generic/kernel/drivers/usb/serial/usbserial.ko` as you said. However the --reinstall command completed successfully but the file doesn't exist still. I did delete the file after I overwrote it incorrectly.

Comment: @ElijahLynn reinstalling `linux-image-extra-4.4.0-116-generic` didn't bring back the file?

Comment: Correct, it did not bring back the file.

Comment: What about purging and reinstalling? as i have added to my answer

Answer (score 2):

Since it doesn't seem like installing is helping I guess you could try to manually download the kernel, extract the files then copy the file over manually.

Download the kernel to the `/tmp` directory:

```
cd /tmp
apt download linux-image-extra-4.4.0-116-generic
```

Next, extract the files from the downloaded `.deb` file:

```
ar -x linux-image-extra-4.4.0-116-generic_4.4.0-116.140_amd64.deb
```

Now, extract the `data.tar.gz` contents:

```
tar xvf data.tar.gz
```

Now you should be able to copy the missing file back to your folder.

```
sudo cp /tmp/lib/modules/4.4.0-116-generic/kernel/drivers/usb/serial/usbserial.ko /lib/modules/4.4.0-116-generic/kernel/drivers/usb/serial/
```

---

Thank you @Olorin for a cool one string command after you download the kernel file using `dpkg-deb` to extract the one file and put it in the designation folder:

```
dpkg-deb --fsys-tarfile linux-image-extra-4.4.0-116-generic_4.4.0-116.140_amd64.deb | sudo tar xv ./lib/modules/4.4.0-116-generic/kernel/drivers/usb/serial/usbserial.ko -C /
```

---

Then clean up your `/tmp` folder or a reboot will clean it:

Hope this helps!

Comment: You can use `dpkg-deb` instead of `ar`: `dpkg-deb --fsys-tarfile linux-image-extra-4.4.0-116-generic_4.4.0-116.140_amd64.deb | tar xv` ... actually the entire operation can be done in one pipeline: `dpkg-deb --fsys-tarfile linux-image-extra-4.4.0-116-generic_4.4.0-116.140_amd64.deb | sudo tar xv lib/modules/4.4.0-116-generic/kernel/drivers/usb/serial/usbserial.ko -C /`

Comment: @Olorin I understand that.  But I test all commands before I put them in my answers.  Unfortunately, that does not work.  Even when I try to extract only the file from the tar.bz2 file it tells me file not found, but when I extract all the contents of it, the file is there and I can copy it.

Comment: @Olorin The command actually needs to be `dpkg-deb --fsys-tarfile linux-image-extra-4.4.0-116-generic_4.4.0-116.140_amd64.deb | sudo tar xv ./lib/modules/4.4.0-116-generic/kernel/drivers/usb/serial/usbserial.ko -C /`  If you list the contents of the bz2 file it shows them with the `./` before the name.  Then it extracts fine.  I will add that to my answer then.

Comment: Ah yes. Another instance of https://xkcd.com/1168/